# Scrapyd getting 504 Deploy failed after cloning server

Tags: nginx, scrapy, scrapyd

I have a running Scrapyd Instance. This instance has been cloned and is now up and running under another server IP. The cloned server workes just fine, except that I can no longer deploy to the new IP.

I am getting

```
  retry_on_eintr(check_call, [sys.executable, 'setup.py', 'clean', '-a', 'bdist_egg', '-d', d],
Deploying to project "test" in http://myip:6843/addversion.json
Deploy failed (504):
<html>
<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Nginx config looks ok (localhost). UFW as well. Ips are correct. The web interface is reachable and so forth. Just deploy failes.

Nginx error log:

```
[error] 1180#1180: *62 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: myip, server: , request: "POST /addversion.json HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:6800/addversion.json", host: "myip:6843"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Found the problem. Scrapy was trying to reach a remote MySQL server which was blocked for this IP.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Scrapy was trying to reach a remote MySQL server which was blocked for this IP.